# Git(hub) keep giving `Host key verification failed` error

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am trying to add ssh-key to my github account but i keep getting `Host key verification failed` error.

[image]

img url: https://image.ibb.co/k94mT8/PDv4oQ.jpg

I have followed this steps: https://help.github.com/articles/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys/

> Generating a new SSH key
>    `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`

> Adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent
>   `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`

> Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account

and tried almost all related stackoverflow answers but the error is still alive.

Where i did wrong?

Edit: **I can clone with https but not with ssh.**

Comment: The image is not available. Please re-upload it here on SO or describe its content.

Comment: Added image url. You can check now. @Polygnome

Comment: Visiting the link gives a `403 Forbidden` error. Unauthenitcated users probably don't have permission to view the image.

Comment: @Norx The URL is no help if the image is not available for the public: "403 Forbidden Request forbidden by administrative rules."

Comment: Sorry about that. Can you see it now?

Answer (score 3):

Run that command. This will probably solve your issue.

```
ssh git@github.com -vvvv
```

Thanks: https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/8m8y56/github_keep_giving_host_key_verification_failed/dzlrvzk/

Answer (score 0):

It's probably late, but anyway. Are you sure that you type 'yes' when terminal asked you: 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?'. If you will be just press Enter - connection will be failure